# Crystal Reports "Login failed for user 'acs_sql'."

Tags: vb6, windows-7, crystal-reports

I've got an app running in VB6 using Crystal Reports version 9 (shutup -- it's been running great for them for 11 years).  I've got MANY crystal reports in this thing, and 99% of them work just fine after our "upgrade" to Windows 7

However, on 1 specific report, when I try to run it from the app, I get the error mentioned above.  I've compared it with a report that works fine, and I can't tell any difference whatsoever between them.  They use ODBC to connect to SQL Server.  They all use the same ODBC DSN.

When I open up Crystal to compare the one that works with the one that doesn't, they look exactly the same!  However, if I hit the "lightning bolt" button to preview the report, the one that works just pulls data, the one that doesn't brings up a box pre-filled with all information except for the password, and I have to enter that.  Only the first time.

**Why is 1 report saving the login credentials, but the 2nd is not?**

I've been pulling my hair out for 2 weeks trying to solve this issue on and off.

Please.  No matter how silly a suggestion might seem to you, I'm willing to give it a try.

Comment: This may sound stupid, but have you tried copying the report to a different computer, opening and saving it, and bringing it back?  I asked a question here a while back about a report that suddenly started behaving differently for one site (after years of working right), and that unexpectedly did the trick.

Comment: First, awesome name.  Second, I'll do that next time I'm at the client's site.  I'll even jump and twirl and do a little dance to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Silly but who knows...

Is it possible that the report has been built using a different machine where the ODBC driver had a different name?

I recall something from my past when IT had set up ODBC drivers with various names and those clients whose ODBC driver name did not match the one in the report had to sign in the first time they ran it.